# I want to run two co-routines parallelly using asyncio module,but they are running synchronously?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
import time

def func():
    print("into the func")
    s = time.time()
    l = []
    for i in range(100000000):
        l.append(i)
    print("time in func is ", time.time() - s)

def func1():
    print("into the func1")
    s = time.time()
    l = []
    for i in range(100000000):
        l.append(i)
    print("time in func1 is ", time.time() - s)


async def exp():
    print("exp started")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    func()
    print("finished exp")
    return [1,2]

async def data():
    print("data started")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    func1()
    # await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    # time.sleep(10)

    print("finished data")
    return {'a':1}

async def start_coros():
# ensure_future -> create_task in Python 3.7
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(coro) for coro in (exp(), data())]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)

asyncio.run(start_coros())
```

output:
exp started
data started
into the func
time in func is  4.8740620613098145
finished exp
into the func1
time in func1 is  4.879637002944946
finished data
total time : 11.467867756756

I need is total time time: 4.879637002944946

Comment: check *gather* [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)

Comment: `async` doesn't mean multithreaded or parallel! Neither `func` nor `func1` ever yields control, so they are never suspended.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Thomas how can I make it run parallel then.

Comment: `threading` or `multiprocessing`.

Comment: can we implement parallellism without using multiprocessing module???

Comment: You can use concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor instead of multiprocessing. But those are really your only options to avoid the GIL.

Comment: Basically, no, not in pure-CPython at least. Either you use multiple thread and are GIL-bound or you use multiple interpreter typically in multiple process. This is how CPython has been designed. This is because Python was born long before multicore processors has become mainstream, but also because all attempts to remove the GIL without sequential overheads failed so far. This is a mess now mainstream processor has many available cores. Even if the GIL issue would be fixed, most module are now not designed to be safely called from a multi-threaded context.

Comment: Modules like Cython (general purpose) or Numba (not general-purpose) can help you since they disable the GIL and do not use the interpreter at all in parallel sections (this is the main deal so for multi-threading not to be GIL-bound, though the truth is a bit more subtle). The thing is your problem appear to be concurency and solving concurrency with multiple thread tends to add more problem than it solve (see deadlock, race condition, cache effects, etc.), especially in Python. To avoid concurrent tasks blocking other ones, you just need to split tasks in smaller ones and use yields.